# HTML5/CSS3 set width/height of <pre> tag text display

Tags: html, css

I have some preformatted text I want to display verbatim in HTML5, so I'm using the *pre* tag. The trouble is that the text comes up in a tiny box with vertical and horizontal scroll bars. I know the size of the text ahead of time and I don't want horizontal or vertical scrolling. I tried using CSS3 to change the size of the pre element, but it does not work. I'm using the latest FireFox, but I would like a cross browser solution.

Any suggestions? Note it's NOT the same as this previously asked question: [pre tag scales over width=100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47000794/pre-tag-scales-over-width-100)

Edit: Here is what I am trying to show. It's some AWK code. Note that it makes no difference if I use a code tag inside the screen tag.

```
/2020</ { # matches year in table
  # strip off MM/DD/YYYY in table
  match($0, "[0-9]?[0-9]/[0-9]?[0-9]/2020", y)
  # save MM/DD to array
  data[++k] = substr(y[0], 1, RLENGTH - 5)
  }
  /,[0-9]{3}</ {
           # matches travel count in table
           # comma seperated count in table
           match($0, "([0-9],)?[0-9]{1,3},[0-9]{3}", t)
           # remove commas
           n = t[0]
           gsub(/,/, "", n)
           # save number in array
           data[++k] = n
           }
           END { # output array as json. json array length is k/3 input length.
           # three consecutive input data values go into one json array row.
           # first is MM/DD as string, second and third are numeric values.
           # output is reverse of input order.
           printf("count = [")
           for(i = k - 2; i > 0; i -= 3) {
                 print("['" data[i] "', " data[i+1] ", " data[i+2] "],")
               }
               print("];")
  }
```

Heres a screen capture of the output:

[image]

Comment: Please share a snippet of your code and possibly a screenshot of the incorrect output.

Comment: use `height: auto; width: auto;`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you are just looking for `white-space: break-spaces;`

```css
pre{
  background: #efefef;
  white-space: break-spaces;
}
```

```html
<pre>        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In varius vel sapien a semper. Ut magna risus, consectetur finibus tempor at, lobortis id diam. Curabitur non felis neque. Donec ac nunc in urna sagittis finibus. Integer consequat, velit ac imperdiet commodo,



     ligula libero interdum urna, sit amet efficitur neque arcu eget tellus. Donec molestie, diam ut accumsan ultricies,       neque ligula iaculis elit, sed pulvinar ex quam laoreet urna. Nulla egestas, nunc ut malesuada pulvinar, eros orci elementum odio, sed iaculis mauris libero ac mi. Integer pulvinar lacus magna, eget semper justo viverra ac.
</pre>
```